# How do I change my wifi router to static?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

The router (TP-Link's TL-WR840N) is connected to a switch, which is connected to the ISP provided router.

I want the devices that connect to it to have to [select static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWc5x.png) and manually fill in the details  in order to connect to the internet.

And for the devices to not be able to connect to the internet if they  [selected the DHCP option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKpi0.png).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

*Screen shots are of wifi setting on Android phone.*

Comment: Disable DHCP on the router.

Comment: I just did that. Didn't work. I'm still able to connect to the internet on DHCP. And yes, I did reboot :D

Comment: @Ramhound a little laymaninsh would be super nice. How can I know which device is acting as a "tour DHCP provider"?  And how can I fix the issue?

Comment: @Ramhound... he says that he has an ISP router connected to a switch, to which he's connecting a WR840N... JJrussel, I skimmed through the WR840N user guide, https://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-WR840N_V2_UG.pdf, and I did not see the screens you provided, so is this access control system actually done by the TP-link or are you using some other solution on top of it? Doesn't the UG explain how to set up the networks? Personally I'd be cautious attaching a router to a network that already has one... that can get messy.

Comment: @Peregrino69 the screenshots are of the wifi settings on my phone. I used to be able to do what I'm wanting to do now. It went back to normal after resetting the router. I'm not sure how it was done before.

Comment: *"The router (TP-Link's TL-WR840N) is connected to a switch ..."* -- Using what port of the TL-WR840N?  A LAN port or the WAN port?  Is this TL-WR840N configured as a default wireless-router or as an Access Point?

Comment: @sawdust WAN port. Not sure if it's configured as a default wireless-router or as an Access Point. How can I find out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the TL-WR840N, but there is a possibility that if both sides of the router are in the same IP range, the router stops routing and acts as a simple switch. If that happens, the ISP router will be serving DHCP to your clients.

First, you want to make sure that the devices you want to control are talking to the TP-Link rather than the ISP router. Next, you want the ranges to be disjoint - if the ISP is serving addresses in the 192.168.0.x subnet, you want the TP-Link to be serving in the 192.168.5.x subnet, or at least not the 192.168.0.x subnet. Then, disable the TP-Link's DHCP server, and you should be good. Note that you may have to go into the ISP's router and disable its WiFi; if it's open or has an easily guessable password, or has guest access available, clients amy end up there.

Comment: How can I make sure the devices are talking to TP-Link and not the ISP router? How can I make the ranges disjoint? What option would that be under in the router settings? I do have access to the ISP router.

Comment: The TP-Link's WiFi SSID will be something you set in the TP-Link's settings; the ISP router will have a different SSID, likely written on the side of the router. You choose, on your machines, which you connect to. To make sure it acts as a router, connect the net cable from the switch to the blue connector of the TP-Link. The TP-Link has a Network page with WAN and LAN subpages; the IP address issued by the ISP router will be on the WAN page. Change the router's IP address on the LAN page to make it a different range.

Comment: I didn't make changes because this is what I see... On the TP-Link... https://i.imgur.com/qRLgTDt.png https://i.imgur.com/sYFaKIc.png

Comment: So that part of it should be fine. Make sure that DHCP is turned off on the DHCP page of the TP-Link. Devices attached to the TP-Link should be set to addresses of the form 192.168.1.x, where x is between 100 and 199, net mask 255.255.255.0, and with a default gateway and DNS server set to 192.168.1.16.